# How can I theme field collection forms?

Tags: theming, entities

I have a field_field_collection in content type (used to field collection module and have unlimited value). It has a number of fields as in the picture below:
[image]

And I want customize theme for it as template as in the picture below:
[image]

How I can I achieve that? I tried to write a template for it, but the result is bad. When I click "add another item" the result looks like shown in the picture under my code below.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    kpr($form);
    print drupal_render($form['title']);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($form['field_field_collection']['und'] as $items){
    if(isset($form['field_field_collection']['und'][$i])) {
        ?>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    print drupal_render($form['field_field_collection']['und'][$i]['field_field_01']);
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    print drupal_render($form['field_field_collection']['und'][$i]['field_field_02']);
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    print drupal_render($form['field_field_collection']['und'][$i]['field_field_3']);
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    print drupal_render($form['field_field_collection']['und'][$i]['field_field_4']);
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php
        $i++;
        }
    }
?>
<?php
    print drupal_render($form['field_field_collection']['und']['add_more']);
    hide($form['actions']);
    hide($form['additional_settings']);
    print drupal_render_children($form);
?>
```

And here is the result when I click "add another item":

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution ? If yes then please share here.

Comment: You didn't find any solution?

Answer (score -2):

If your requirement is to format Field Collection in **Table Format**, then [Field Collection Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) Module will help.

Comment: Field Collection Table module can not help me

Comment: That's for frontend display, OP wants node form.